# Adding a Clickable Dot to a World Map Using JQuery VMap

Tags: jqvmap

I've recently inherited a project which is using jqvmap.
There's a map of the world with a column of clickable dots on it:

[image]

Whilst I have been able to find the code which seems to add those dots, I cannot figure out how this data was generated:

```
jQuery.fn.vectorMap('addMap', 'world_en', {
    "width": 950, "height": 550, "paths": {
        "id": { "path": "M781.68,324.4l-2.31,8.68l-12.53,4.", ... ... ... "name": "Pakistan" },
        "in": { "path": "M670.98,313.01l4.58-2.24l2.72-9,"... ... ... "name": "India" },
        "np": { "path": "M671.19,242.56l0.46,4.2, ... ... ... "name": "Greece" },

        "demo": {
            "path": "M922.59,148a8.59,8.59,0,1,1-8.59-8.59C918.76,139,922.59,143.27,922.59,148Z",
            "name": "Demo"
        },
        "Demo2": {
            "path": "M922.59,80A8.59,8.59,0,1,1,914,71.42C918.76,71,922.59,75.27,922.59,80Z",
            "name": "Demo2"
        },
        "Demo3": {
            "path": "M922.59,114a8.59,8.59,0,1,1-8.59-8.59C918.76,105,922.59,109.27,922.59,114Z",
            "name": "Demo3"
        },
        "Demo4": {
            "path": "M922.59,182a8.59,8.59,0,1,1-8.59-8.59C918.76,173,922.59,177.27,922.59,182Z",
            "name": "Demo4"
        },
        "Demo5": {
            "path": "M922.59,216a8.59,8.59,0,1,1-8.59-8.59C918.76,207,922.59,211.27,922.59,216Z",
            "name": "Demo5"
        }
}
});
```

I need to add another dot.
Is there a tool which the previous developer has used?
Is there a guide somewhere which explains how to go about doing such a thing.

I've searched Google and looked at the Github site for vmap and have not found anything which could explain this.

Here's the code in jquery's ready function which set's the map up:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#hidCountrySU").val('');
    $("#hidServerCode").val('');
    $('#lblServerName').text(' Select server to test ');
    $('#btnSubmitServer').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    // List of Regions we'll let clicks through for
    let enabledRegions = ['demo', 'demo2', 'demo3', 'demo4', 'demo5'];

    let map = null;
    // Store currentRegion
    let currentRegion = 'demo';

    map = $('#vmap').vectorMap({
        map: 'world_en',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        color: '#ffffff',
        hoverOpacity: 0.7,
        selectedColor: '#F90606',
        enableZoom: false,
        showTooltip: true,
        values: sample_data,
        scaleColors: ['#C8EEFF', '#006491'],
        colors: {
            demo: '#F78774',
            demo2: '#F78774',
            demo3: '#F78774',
            demo4: '#F78774',
            demo5: '#F78774'
        },
        normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
        selectedRegions: ['aue'],
        onRegionClick: function (event, code, region) {
            // Check if this is an eabled region, and not the current selected on
            if (enabledRegions.indexOf(code) === -1) {
                // Not an enabled region
                event.preventDefault();
            } else {
                // Enabled region. Update newly selected region.
                currentRegion = code;
                $('.selectedRegionColor').removeClass('selectedRegionColor');
                $('#jqvmap1_' + code).addClass('selectedRegionColor');
            }
        },
        onRegionSelect: function (event, code, region) {
            localStorage.setItem("locationSelected", "true");
        
            if (code == 'demo') {
                $("#hidCountrySU").val('countryAU');
                $("#hidServerCode").val('demo');
                $('#lblServerName').text(' demo testing ');
                $('#btnSubmitServer').removeAttr('disabled');
            } else if (code == 'demo2') {
                $("#hidCountrySU").val('countryAU');
                $("#hidServerCode").val('demo2');
                $('#lblServerName').text(' demo2 testing ');
                $('#btnSubmitServer').removeAttr('disabled');
            } else if (code == 'demo3') {
                $("#hidCountrySU").val('countryAU');
                $("#hidServerCode").val('Demo3');
                $('#lblServerName').text(' Demo3 testing ');
                $('#btnSubmitServer').removeAttr('disabled');
            } else if (code == 'demo4') {
                $("#hidCountrySU").val('countryAU');
                $("#hidServerCode").val('demo4');
                $('#lblServerName').text(' B Demo ');
                $('#btnSubmitServer').removeAttr('disabled');
            } else if (code == 'demo5') {
                $("#hidCountrySU").val('countryAU');
                $("#hidServerCode").val('demo5');
                $('#lblServerName').text(' demo5 ');
                $('#btnSubmitServer').removeAttr('disabled');
          

            if ($("#form_ServerSubmitFromServer").length === 1) {

                $("#form_ServerSubmitFromServer").submit();
            }
            else if ($("#form_ServerSubmitFormServer2").length === 1) {

                $("#form_ServerSubmitFormServer2").submit();
            }

          
        },
        onLabelShow: function (event, label, code) {
            if (enabledRegions.indexOf(code) === -1) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Obviously the first snippet is extending the vectorMap.

I can only assume the previous dev used some kind of image editing program like Inkscape to add the dot and somehow get the path for it. But I just don't know.

Thanks

Comment: The "path" property seems to describe the coordinates for the colored parts of the map. If you can provide us with the code sample, we can further help you.

Comment: @JakobSchweighofer I've added more code to the question. Not sure how to generate a new "path" for the new dot.

Comment: Thank you. It is hard to tell from this, but your guess with Inkscape seems pretty accurate: Someone used an SVG for the world map and extracted the coordinates from certain countries. This is what gets colored. If you can find the path for the target country, you could try to do the same. Good luck!

Comment: @JakobSchweighofer Thanks. Will see how I go.

Comment: Mostly got this working. There's one suboptimal aspect to my solution. The path format is not the same as the existing paths. E.g. my new dot's path is `m 922.58935,250.00149 a 8.589831,8.5915677 0 1 1 -8.58984,-8.59157 c 4.75994,-0.41007 8.58984,3.8607 8.58984,8.59157 z` whereas the existing dots have no spaces and uppercase. Not sure why.

Comment: Great job! According to this article (https://css-tricks.com/svg-path-syntax-illustrated-guide/) uppercase means absolute and lowercase means relative paths. I really can't tell when there is a need for spaces or not. I wouldn't stress the minimal difference in format if it works imo.

Comment: @JakobSchweighofer Thanks for that link. I'll take a look. Might research how to convert an absolute path to a relative one. Otherwise, I'll put a ribbon on this. Glad I spent some of my "mispent youth" playing around with Inkscape years ago. Saved me heaps of time now.